# Why additional constraint is need for this two groups to be isomorphic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

I'm reading AMS's book *Papers on Topology*, which collects Poincare's papers on topology.

However, the first paper stops me.

In the paper, he considered the group generated by transformations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the generators are:

$(x,y,z)\rightarrow (x+1,y,z)$

$(x,y,z)\rightarrow (x,y+1,z)$

$(x,y,z)\rightarrow(\alpha x+\beta y,\gamma x+\delta y, z+1)$

where $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1$.

Obviously, the third transformation is a rotation in $XY$-plane and one move in $Z$.

We denote the group generated above by $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$.

Then Poincare claims that two groups $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ and $(\alpha',\beta',\gamma',\delta')$ cannot be isomorphism unless the two transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$(x,y)\rightarrow(\alpha x+\beta y,\gamma x+\delta y)$

$(x,y)\rightarrow(\alpha' x+\beta' y,\gamma' x+\delta' y)$

are conjugate of each other by a linear transformation with integer coefficient.

I'm confused by this claim and can not find why.

I think if we denote the three transformation $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_1',\sigma_2',\sigma_3'$, we can just form an isomorphism: $\phi(\sigma_i)=\sigma_i'$.

Why the additional constraint is needed?

Comment: Because terminology changes over time?

Comment: The book has corrected some terminology different.

Comment: Have you tried proving that your map $\phi$ is an isomorphism so you can see where the argument goes wrong?

Comment: @Steven, I tried, but I have not deal with algebra for a long time, so a little bit puzzled. I think I should examine that $Ker\phi$ should be 1. However, I think it is obviously true because each $\sigma$ plus 1 in certain direction, so $Ker\phi$ has only one elements, I think.

Comment: hx:  The problem is not to compute the kernel; it's to show that the map is well defined.

Comment: @hx: even if you cannot prove that the groups are not isomorphic in general, certainly some matrices give different groups. For example, if the matrix is the identity, the group is Abelian. If the matrix is torsion (say, its cube equal to 1), then the group contains torsion, etc. So your map cannot in principle always be a homomorphism. 

Comment: @Steven, @Mark, I realized the problem, my function is wrong. However I still cannot find a right argument. Can you show me more details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Poincare was correct. These are Abelian ($\mathbb{Z}^2$)-by-cyclic groups where the cyclic group acts on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ll}\alpha & \gamma \\\ \beta & \delta\end{array}\right)$. These groups are isomorphic if and only if the matrices are conjugate in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Here is more about the proof. Consider two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ which are extensions of normal subgroups $H_1, H_2$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by cyclic groups $\langle c_i\rangle$, $i=1,2$ acting (by conjugation) as matrices $M_1, M_2$ from $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose that there exists an isomorphism $\phi$ from $G_1$ onto $G_2$. Assume that the eigenvalues of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not on the unit circle (otherwise the situation is also easy but somewhat different). Then prove that $\phi$ must take $H_1$ onto $H_2$ because $G_i$ has only one maximal normal Abelian subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. We can assume then that $H_1=H_2$ and $\phi$ acts as a matrix $N$ on $H_1$. Then $N$ conjugates $M_1$ to $M_2$ (from the definition of homomorphism). I do not know how Poincare proved it (in his paper, there is no proof or reference). Perhaps his proof was more geometric. One can also use more modern technique like rigidity theorems.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept "Abelian-by-cyclic groups" and cannot find some helpful information on google neither. Could you briefly describe what an Abelian-by-cyclic groups is and why the conclusion is correct?


Comment: P-by-Q group means a group with a normal subgroup with Property P s.t. the quotient has Property Q.

Comment: I tried to prove it all the afternoon, but failed. Can you give me some more hint or reference?

Comment: $G$ is Abelian-by-cyclic means that $G$ is a semidirect product of an abelian group (in this case $\mathbb Z_2$) with a cyclic group.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathbb Z^2$, and not to have the 2 in the subscript...

Comment: Beautiful proof!

Comment: @Samuelson, got it, thx~

Comment: @Peter P-by-Q does not mean the extension is a semidirect product (i.e. is split), although it indeed is in the present case.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are interested in topology, you would do well to read Peter Scott's beautiful paper from 1983, called "The geometries of 3-manifolds". The manifolds you are asking about are Solvmanifolds (at least in the case @Mark Sapir is discussing in his answer), and are discussed in detail starting on page 470 of that paper (including an answer to your question), but you would do well to read the whole thing.

Comment: Great! It is very very helpful! 